# Multilangual content in single website: should I seperate content by language?

Tags: seo, internationalization, technical-seo, localization

I'm building a website where I plan to publish some content in two languages: Arabic and French.

Since this is a one-man job, I wanted to avoid unnecessary complexity and have one single page to list all published articles ― regardless of their language. Most people here are able to read both languages, even though some might be more comfortable with one than the other.

All the guidance Google is offering on the topic supposes that multilingual content is the result of having multiple versions of one website to accommodate different audiences, which is not the case here.

One big difference between the two cases is that, on my site, the content in one language is NOT a translated version of the others'. For example, articles in French might include "How to wash your car?" and "Tips to save on gas", while the Arabic ones would be about "Five tips for a healthier engine" and "How to check your tires".

If I understood correctly, this means that I can't use `hreflang` to specify each article's language since the pages are not alternates of other ones. Is this correct? It it is, what can I do to tell Google what language a page is in?

And most importantly, would juxtaposing content in such a manner hurt the SEO of the website?

Answer (score 1):

> If I understood correctly, this means that I can't use hreflang to
> specify each article's language since the pages are not alternates of
> other ones. Is this correct? It it is, what can I do to tell Google
> what language a page is in?

Yes, you understand **[Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions?hl=en)** correctly:

> If you have multiple versions of a page for different languages or
> regions, tell Google about these different variations.

---

> It it is, what can I do to tell Google what language a page is in?

**[Google says](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/managing-multi-regional-sites?hl=en#make-sure-the-page-language-is-obvious)**:

> Google uses the visible content of your page to determine its
> language. ... You can help Google determine the language correctly by
> using a single language for content and navigation on each page, and
> by avoiding side-by-side translations.
>
> Translating only the boilerplate text of your pages while keeping the
> bulk of your content in a single language (as often happens on pages
> featuring user-generated content) can create a bad user experience if
> the same content appears multiple times in search results with various
> boilerplate languages.

and

> Use language-specific URLs